# Is there a non spammy, no registering, free site to download old drivers?

Tags: drivers

From time to time I need to reinstall some ancient system. Replace hardware with other abandoned hardware. Whenever I search for drivers Google returns sites requiring logins and/or payment. Where are the nice places to find and download old drivers?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not going to help you find *really* ancient drivers, but [64bitdrivers.com](http://64bitdrivers.com) is pretty much beyond reproach, as far as I've been able to tell. Honest site, free downloads, no spam.

Answer (score 1):

OEM - Original manufacturer's site will always be the winner.  Any site that gathers them all up and hosts them separately is going to have an ulterior motive.  If you're lucky, it's just to get ad clickthrus.

This can be its own wild goose chase, but I have yet to dead-end on drivers for old hardware this way.

Comment: I always try the manufacturers site, but sometimes the manufacturer is long gone, merged around n'th times etc ...

Answer (score 0):

I always try to use OEM.  If that fails I immediately try driverguide.  It used to be pretty awesome, but now requires authentication.

It also tries to trick you into ordering a CD instead of downloading the driver if you arent careful.